# Figma text orientation

Tags: css, figma

I started using figma as web design tool.
I can't seem to find text-orientation vertical.

In CSS it would be:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: upright;
```

Is there such option or workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, you can rotate to get that effect.
I think you are trying to do something like

[image: figma]

If you need something like above.

In css:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: upright;
```

In figma:

You need to **rotate** the text to get that effect.

> In Top Right corner below the height and width value you will find the
> option from where you can rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

[Vertical writing effect in figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtgnE.png)

If you are looking for a effect like this you just need to drag through the width of text area boundary and it will be in this effect.

you can not find the inspect code in figma like below but it is what is meant..

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
text-orientation: upright;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the text in order to compact it and get a result like this
[image: vertical test in figma]

Look how the width is only 11 in this case, and the height fits with the hole vertical text.

Answer (score 0):

select the text . Than change the degree of orientation accordingly.only you have to move your mouse on the degree icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an effect similar to this, all you have to do is drag through the border of the text area's width.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).